# Mysql import/export

Tags: database, import, export

I have a database schema, I worked on it in a local computer, now I want to put this schema to our server(the database size more than 1Tb), but it's really huge to use import/export. If it's necessary I will take out the HDD. Are there any easy solutions, for example that I can point to that folder where the database is, and that's all, Or it really necessary to us export/import tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your database directory on the server if you have uniform configs on both computers.